# Static files are not loading for Django product on Digital Ocean

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

I am about to publish my first Django project on a Digital Ocean droplet. I was following the official Digital Ocean guide to install Django on a droplet (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04#creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn) and everything worked fine but the serving of static files.

Here are key parts of my files:

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEBUG = False

COMPRESS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is my folder structure on digital ocean:

```
root/
    snap/
    gymtracker/
        gymenv/
        gymtracker/
            gymtrackerapp/
            static/
```

I see on in the terminal on digital ocean that all static files are in this location:

> /root/gymtracker/gymtracker/static/

but when I load the page I get 403 for the static files ( the page loads fine otherwise):

> Request Method: GET

> Status Code: 403 Forbidden

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

The Digital Ocean tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04#creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn) missed one important Nginx config change at the end to make your static resources show up.

After you follow the tutorial you need to edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and change the user from www-data to your username (e.g sammy) by running

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The other solution works, while there are few alternatives. I think the safest way is to move the /static/ folder out of /home/{user}/ directory

Creating the directories and setting permissions:

> sudo mkdir -pv /var/www/{project_name_or_domain_etc}/static/
>
> sudo chown -cR {user}:{user} /var/www/{project_name_or_domain_etc}/

Now changing the NGINX config:

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/{project_name_or_domain_etc}

replace the "`location /static/`" part with

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/{project_name_or_domain_etc}/static/;
}
```

> sudo systemctl restart nginx

Will need to change the **DJANGO settings** as well, replace the "`STATIC_URL =` " lines with:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/{project_name_or_domain_etc}/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

Now run **collectstatic** and it should work! Based on https://realpython.com/django-nginx-gunicorn/#serving-static-files-directly-with-nginx

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the permissions `nginx` has over the generated `static` folder. There's no need to modify your Django settings, `static` folder location or `nginx.conf` values. Instead, the following should be sufficient.

Assuming the Ubuntu@22 user "sammy" is running `nginx` run:

1. `sudo usermod -a -G sammy www-data`
2. `sudo chown -R :www-data /home/sammy/your_django_project_directory`

This will result in `nginx` having enough permissions to access your static files. To test this out, you can try loading the files from a web browser like `<your-domain-or-ip-address>/static/admin/css/base.css`.